# How to see the error log of icescrum server startup?

Tags: windows-7, logging, error-logging

I want to use icescrum on windows 7. It has been installed (ver R6#7.1). But, when I click on the start/stop button, it reports an error:

```
An error occurred when executing command: startup
```

I could not find a way to see more details. How can I check the source of the error?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the path to the log file (from the documentations: https://www.kagilum.com/documentation/icescrum-server/): "If there is an error of if your iceScrum doesn’t start, you should have a look at your logs. You should find them in your user’s home application data directory, in a Kagilum/iceScrum Server/logs folder."